# iOS/Swift Core data merge conflict

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

For updating data in core data(When there was already data in the core data), I deleted all data and then re-insert the data. but I have no idea why the merge conflict occurred.
I'm not familiar with Core data yet, so I can't figure out what's wrong with it.
I guess I need to change my deleteAll function, but I don't know what to change.

The code is as below.

```
Could not merge changes.
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133020 "Could not merge changes." UserInfo={conflictList=(
    "NSMergeConflict (0x6000008fdd00) for NSManagedObject (0x600003e80e60) with objectID '0x95773100e3922989 <x-coredata://60FADEF9-22B4-46FC-B17C-2B722FE843F7/Languages/p79417>' with oldVersion = 1 and newVersion = <deleted> and old object snapshot = {\n    code = es;\n    icon = spain;\n    isChecked = 0;\n    title = Spanish;\n}",
    "NSMergeConflict (0x6000008fda00) for NSManagedObject (0x600003e80aa0) with objectID '0x95773100e2722989 <x-coredata://60FADEF9-22B4-46FC-B17C-2B722FE843F7/Languages/p79414>' with oldVersion = 1 and newVersion = <deleted> and old object snapshot = {\n    code = fr;\n    icon = france;\n    isChecked = 1;\n    title = French;\n}",
    "NSMergeConflict (0x6000008fdbc0) for NSManagedObject (0x600003e80cd0) with objectID '0x95773100e3322989 <x-coredata://60FADEF9-22B4-46FC-B17C-2B722FE843F7/Languages/p79420>' with oldVersion = 1 and newVersion = <deleted> and old object snapshot = {\n    code = cn;\n    icon = china;\n    isChecked = 0;\n    title = Chineses;\n}",
    "NSMergeConflict (0x6000008fdd80) for NSManagedObject (0x600003e80d20) with objectID '0x95773100e3d22989 <x-coredata://60FADEF9-22B4-46FC-B17C-2B722FE843F7/Languages/p79419>' with oldVersion = 1 and newVersion = <deleted> and old object snapshot = {\n    code = kr;\n    icon = \"south-korea\";\n    isChecked = 0;\n    title = Korean;\n}",
    "NSMergeConflict (0x6000008fdc80) for NSManagedObject (0x600003e80b40) with objectID '0x95773100e2122989 <x-coredata://60FADEF9-22B4-46FC-B17C-2B722FE843F7/Languages/p79413>' with oldVersion = 1 and newVersion = <deleted> and old object snapshot = {\n    code = us;\n    icon = \"united-states-of-america\";\n    isChecked = 1;\n    title = English;\n}",
    "NSMergeConflict (0x6000008fddc0) for NSManagedObject (0x600003e80dc0) with objectID '0x95773100e3f22989 <x-coredata://60FADEF9-22B4-46FC-B17C-2B722FE843F7/Languages/p79418>' with oldVersion = 1 and newVersion = <deleted> and old object snapshot = {\n    code = jp;\n    icon = japan;\n    isChecked = 0;\n    title = Japanese;\n}",
    "NSMergeConflict (0x6000008fdb80) for NSManagedObject (0x600003e809b0) with objectID '0x95773100e2522989 <x-coredata://60FADEF9-22B4-46FC-B17C-2B722FE843F7/Languages/p79415>' with oldVersion = 1 and newVersion = <deleted> and old object snapshot = {\n    code = ru;\n    icon = russia;\n    isChecked = 1;\n    title = Russian;\n}",
    "NSMergeConflict (0x6000008fda40) for NSManagedObject (0x600003e801e0) with objectID '0x95773100e3b22989 <x-coredata://60FADEF9-22B4-46FC-B17C-2B722FE843F7/Languages/p79416>' with oldVersion = 1 and newVersion = <deleted> and old object snapshot = {\n    code = it;\n    icon = italy;\n    isChecked = 1;\n    title = Italien;\n}"
), NSExceptionOmitCallstacks=true}
```

```swift
private var persistenceManager = PersistenceManager.shared
private let request: NSFetchRequest<Languages> = Languages.fetchRequest()
private var coreDataLanguages: [Languages]

..

persistenceManager.deleteAll(request: request)
coreDataLanguages.forEach { language in    
    let language = Setting(isChecked: language.isChecked, title: language.title!, code: language.code!, icon: language.icon!)
    persistenceManager.insertLanguage(language: language)
}
```

```swift
class PersistenceManager {
    
    static var shared: PersistenceManager = PersistenceManager()
    
    var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Setting")
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
    
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return self.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    func saveContext() {
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
                print("Data Saved to Context")
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    @discardableResult
    func insertLanguage(language: Setting) -> Bool {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Languages", in: self.context)
        if let entity = entity {
            let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: self.context)
            managedObject.setValue(language.isChecked, forKey: "isChecked")
            managedObject.setValue(language.title, forKey: "title")
            managedObject.setValue(language.code, forKey: "code")
            managedObject.setValue(language.icon, forKey: "icon")
            
            do {
                try self.context.save()
                return true
            } catch {
                print(error)
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return false
            }
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    @discardableResult
    func deleteAll<T: NSManagedObject>(request: NSFetchRequest<T>) -> Bool {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = T.fetchRequest()
        let delete = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: request)
        
        do {
            try self.context.execute(delete)
            try self.context.save()
            return true
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

I can use saveContext for saving my core data but I need to change the position as well and it didn't work after rebooting. After rebooting, the order of elements was like I set for the first time. So I want to know why if I delete all data, it doesn't work.

I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Batch delete requests go directly to the persistent store, bypassing your managed object context. It's not clear when you're seeing that error (on save during the delete, or on save during the insert?) but it's probably caused because the context thought an object existed, then you deleted it from the store, without letting the context know.

Since you're only dealing with a small number of objects you would probably be better off not doing a batch insert (since you'd need to update the context with the results anyway, why not just delete them individually then save).

Better still would be to perform an upsert (update / insert) which would keep each language object intact and just update the properties. This would maintain any relationships between objects and prevent you having inaccessible faults if other parts of your code were holding references to the language objects.

You can read about upserts in core data here: https://www.upbeat.it/upsert-in-core-data/